# ASP.NET Core 3.1: Web API identity sign in

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi

I am creating **CookieAutentecation signin** for my Web API.

I have read and followed the [official article here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and I have done everything correctly as far as I am concerned.

But when I put breakpoints in my controllers and inspect `HttpContext.User`, everything is always null, no Username, no claims, nothing.

What else do I need to make this work? Are additional steps needed for Web API vs MVC app?

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors();

    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, act => {
                act.LoginPath = "/api/login";
                act.AccessDeniedPath = "/api/login";
                act.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });

    services.AddControllers();

    services.AddServices(); // <- Own app domain services 
    services.AddDataAccess(); // <- Own app domain data access
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseCors(
            options => options.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
        );

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
}
```

**api/login**

```
var user = new SecurityUser()
        {
            UserID = 123,
            CompleteName = "Test user",
            FirstName = "Test",
            Email = "test.user@123.com"
        };
var identity = user.ToClaimsIdentity(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, 123);
        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), new AuthenticationProperties()
        {
            AllowRefresh = true,
           ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
           IsPersistent = true,
        });
```

`ToClaimsIdentity` extension method:

```
public static ClaimsIdentity ToClaimsIdentity(this SecurityUser user, string authenticantionType, int auditUserID)
{
        var claims = new List<Claim>()
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.UserID.ToString()),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.FirstName),
            new Claim(SecurityUserClaimTypes.AuditUserID, auditUserID.ToString())
        };

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, authenticantionType);
        return identity;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit - This is what I am taking about** 
[image]

Comment: Have you added `[Authorize]` to your controllers?

Comment: `[Authorize]` checked the `User.IsAuthorized` - But there is no user at all - So adding `[Authorize]` to controllers just prevents me from accessing the controller and returns a `404`

Comment: I just copied the code snippets above to a new Web Api project template, generated a cookie, and when I sent the cookie back, the HttpContext.User ClaimsPrincipal was correctly populated with the claims set previously. So I cannot repro the issue.

Do I understand correctly that you're generating a cookie, and then trying to send another request with the cookie included? Because if you're checking in the same request as the sign-in, it won't be populated yet; only when ASP.NET runs authentication on the received cookie.

Comment: I have a client app (Blazor) and my web API, they are on different ports.
First of all I do a request to `api/login` then (**another controller**) `api/production` - This is where I am inspecting the `User.Identity` - It's not creating the Cookie at all - When I do F12 dev tools, nothing there either

Comment: Is there any cross-origin setting I need to enable? As they are both on different ports?

Comment: That's a good point. Yes, CORS needs to be configured for cookie authentication to work. I won't write an answer, because I haven't worked with cookies for quite a while, but this blog post seem to discuss the exact same issue: https://www.blinkingcaret.com/2018/07/18/secure-an-asp-net-core-web-api-using-cookies/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help guys!

I finally realised it was a client thing, I did three things:

- CORS was an issue, in my `.UseCors` method call my my Api I allowed credentials:
  `.AllowCredentials()`
- My client app in using Blazor, I found [this article here](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2018/09/07/blazor-apis.aspx) which told me I needed to set the http request configuration to include credentials, so in my client side app startup.cs:
  `WebAssemblyHttpMessageHandlerOptions.DefaultCredentials = FetchCredentialsOption.Include;`
- I am using Http not Https on my local, and Chrome was complaining about SameSite, so im my Api StartUp.cs, where I call `AddAuthentication...AddCookie` I added this:
  `options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;`

I don't fully understand the SameSite... and I have also come across **JSON Web Tokens (JWT)**.
But I'm not interested, as long as it's working. ;-)